# Column highlighting issue using JQuery Tablesorter Pager

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter, pager

basically what is happening is that i have a table using the JQuery Table Sorter and when you click on an element within the thead, the column is sorted and i add a class of highlighted to it. This i have no issue with.

When i add in the Pager plugin for the table sorter everything goes topsy turvey! It is like the cellIndex is changing so the highlighting doesnt continue across all the pages of the pager!! Its extreamly anoying!! Any help would be fantastic!!

Cheers,
Fitz

Comment: Without seeing what you are doing we cannot do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing... But when you use the zebra widget, it, by default adds class names of "odd" and "even" for styling. So just change the `widgetZebra` option to match your css styling:

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    widgets     : ['zebra'],
    widgetZebra : { css: ["odd","even"] }
});
```